# Compact smooth surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with constant mean curvature and positive Gaussian curvature is a sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces, curvature

I need to show that a regular ,closed, compact, orientable surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with constant mean curvature $H$, and positive Gaussian curvature(not necessarily constant) must be a sphere. The proof given in solution is to show that the two principal curvatures must be equal everywhere on this surface and this surface is umbilical everywhere. I know what's after this, but I don't understant how to show that the surface is umbilical everywhere. How should I show it?

Comment: "In the mid-twentieth century, Heinz Hopf showed that the only constant mean curvature surface of genus zero is a round sphere. On the other hand Pavel Alexandrov observed that every compact embedded constant mean curvature surface is a round sphere. The question naturally arose whether compact embedded constant mean curvature surfaces existed with higher genus. This question was resolved in the affirmative by the discovery of the the first constant mean curvature torus by Henry Wente in the mid nineteen eighties" https://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/user/nick/gallery/WenteTorus.html

Comment: so, what is the source of the problem, and what is being discussed in the pages before the question?

Comment: It's from a past exam paper....

Comment: So I wonder if there would be a short proof of this. The course is differential geometry of curves and surfaces, in which they only study $\mathbb{R}^3$, and the relavent tools they introduced are not more than fundamental forms, Gaussian curvatures, mean curvatures, principal curvatures etc.

Comment: Yes, there is indeed a short proof. This is a standard exercise using Hilbert’s lemma as in the proof of Liebmann’s Theorem. See section 3 of chapter 2 of my differential geometry text, linked in my profile. Note Exercise 8 on p. 65.

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful!

Comment: Write an answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof, using the Hilbert's lemma:
Let $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ be principal curvatures such that $\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2$. Since $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=2H$ is constant, if at point $p$ $\lambda_1$ reaches minimum then $\lambda_2$ reaches maximum at $p$. By Hilbert's lemma, if $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$ at $p$ then $K(p)<0$, which contradicts with our assumption that $K>0$. Thus $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2$ at $p$, so $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ at $p$, it follows that $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ everywhere on the surface, so $K>0$ is also constant and the surface must be a sphere.